# Mock Hibernate transactionalDao

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am unable to mock any methods from `TransactionalDao`.

Note :- T is my entity class.

Code flow is like this.

```
public class MainClassImpl extends TransactionalDao<T> implements MainClass{

     public Set<T> method1(Set<T> setOfTypeT){
            return super.addOrUpdate(setOfTypeT);
     }
}
```

My test class:

```
public class MainClassTest{
      @Test
      public void method1Test(){
            MainClassImpl spy= Mockito.spy(new MainClassImpl());

            Set<T> setTest= new HashSet<T>();
            Mockito.doReturn(setTest).when((TransactionalDao<T>)spy).addOrUpdate(setTest);

            spy.addOrUpdateDeviceDetails(setTest);  
      }
}
```

When I am running it in debug mode it is calling `TransactionalDao` and trying to execute it. 
How can we mock `TransactionalDao`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can mock such behaviour in Mockito.

I would advise the following (in that order):

**1)** If you dont override the addOrUpdate method, then remove the super prefix from the method call, then Mockito will mock that method:

```
public Set<T> method1(Set<T> setOfTypeT){
        return addOrUpdate(setOfTypeT);
}
```

**2)** Not sure what motivates you to actually extends the Service class with a Dao class. In my opinion you should opt for composition. When you would use the Dao as the dependency then mocking that method would not be a problem anymore.

**3)** If you cannot go for any of the above then you are left with some custom workarounds like the following:

```
public class MainClassImpl extends TransactionalDao<T> implements MainClass{
 public Set<T> method1(Set<T> setOfTypeT){
        return baseAddOrUpdate(setOfTypeT);
 }

 public Set<T> baseAddOrUpdate(Set<T> setOfTypeT){
     return super.addOrUpdate(setOfTypeT);
 }
}
```

Test

```
public class MainClassTest{
      @Test
      public void method1Test(){
            MainClassImpl spy= Mockito.spy(new MainClassImpl());

            Set<T> setTest= new HashSet<T>();
            Mockito.doReturn(setTest).when(spy).baseAddOrUpdate(setTest);

            spy.addOrUpdateDeviceDetails(setTest);  
      }
}
```

Bottom line is, if this is not some old legacy code that you cannot touch, then go for option 2.. the whole application will benefit.